# Installing an SSL Certificate in Windows Server 2008 using powershell

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, command-line-interface, powershell

Is it possible to Install an SSL Certificate in Windows Server 2008 R2 using powershell?

If it's not, is it possible with cmd command line?

I am doing it with mmc now but would it be nice to do that with PowerShell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `certutil.exe`. The exact syntax varies based on the the certificate file format (.cer, .pfx...), but one of these options should be able to do the trick:

```
certutil -addstore my <filename>
certutil -installcert <filename>
certutil -importcert <filename>
certutil -importpfx <filename>
```

More info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772898(WS.10).aspx.

---

This also *can* be done in native PowerShell, but it's a lot more complex, as there is no built-in command for certificate management, so you have to use the .NET X.509 library (`System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates`).

Comment: thanks for the info. Today, I was exporting SSLs from win server 2003 and importing them into win server 2008 r2. is this certutil.exe utility from microsoft? any resource you can recommend for me to go over?

Comment: Yes, it's a built-in tool in Windows systems; for detailed syntax, see the link I added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No time for a sf.com-quality answer, but someone please feel free to improve it, thankyou

[Public Key Infrastructure PowerShell module](http://pspki.codeplex.com/)

[PowerShell Certificate Provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347615.aspx)